# value not available in create event on jQuery UI slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

```
$('#foo').slider({
  range: 'min',
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  step: 100,
  value: 500,
  create: function( event, ui) {
          var bar = ui.value;
  },
  //etc...
});
```

Why is `bar` undefined and not `500`? Is it possible to assign a variable to the `value` in the `create` event?

Comment: The above code is not sufficient to say why. How is `create` being invoked?

Comment: where is create defined... Please post the full source

Comment: This is a built-in callback in jquery-ui.  It is well-documented.  I don't think he should have to post the source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use

```
create: function( e, ui ) {
    var bar=$(this).slider('value');
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/yBMZv/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused on why `ui.value` doesn't work, but this works for me.

Comment: You are most welcome :-) described here http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ in `methods` section.

Comment: For some reason the create callback was not invoked in my case, so I had to bind the event maunaly before creating slider $('.slider').on('create', function(event, ui){...}); and then trigger the create event manually too after creating slider like, $('.slider').slider().trigger('create');

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you'd need to get the value when you're instantiating the slider since you're setting it anyway, but you can do it this way:

```
$('#foo').slider({
  range: 'min',
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  step: 100,
  value: 500,
  create: function( event, ui) {
          var bar = $('#foo').slider("value");
  },
  //etc...
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t2SUn/)**.

Comment: You might need that value if for example you're using a permanent tooltip on the handle to show the current value. Ideally you would only set the value for the slider and instantiate the tooltip once the slider is created (i.e. using the "create" callback).

Answer (score 0):

The ui parameter for create method is empty as per their API documentation hence var bar = ui.value is undefined just in case anyone wondered why it did not work.

Please see [reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create)